# cat command replace text Linux shell script

Tags: 14.04, cat

I have shell script file. In there is code like: `<tag>port:8080</tag>`.
I want to replace this code line with another code line: `<tag>port:3128</tag>`.
How do I do that?
I used `cat`, but it removed all the code lines and only added this code line..can anyone tell me how to replace the text in shell scripting ?
This is how I tryed it:

```
cat <<EOF > /home/samples/pom.xml
<tag>port:3128</tag>
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general command is `sed -i 's/old/new/g' yourfile`.
But you have to escape special characters with `\`.

So the command is: `sed -i 's/<tag>port:8080<\/tag>/<tag>port:3128<\/tag>/g' /home/samples/pom.xml`

For the path it is::
`sed -i 's/<path>home\/user\/location<\/path>/<path>\/user\/tmp\/location2<\/path>/g' /path/to/file`

Comment: hi this is the one i want to change.<app.lib>D:\\app\\lib</app.lib>. to <app.lib>D:\\app2\\lib</app.lib> How i want to change.i will appreciate your he

Comment: `sed -i 's/<app.lib>D:\\\\app\\\\lib<\/app.lib>/<app.lib>D:\\\\app2\\\\lib<\/app.lib>/g' yourfile`

Comment: No big deal, just learn the syntax for the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is YOURFILE in the current directory, try
`sed -i 's/8080/3128/g' YOURFILE`

This will replace all occurences of 8080 with 3128.

Comment: Thanks how we replace sentence using sed.like this one i have another chjange for change path in xml.<path>home/user/location</path> to <path>/user/tmp/location2</path>

Comment: hi this is the one i want to change.<app.lib>D:\\app\\lib</app.lib>. How i want to change.i will appreciate your help